# Is it possible to require a TypeScript file that has import statements into a JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I have a webpack.config.js-file in my typescript-project. I want to import some mock data to inject as a template parameter in HtmlWebpackPlugin. The problem is that the mock-data is a typescript file that has import statements, and when I try to import it I get an error:

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Here is an example of the mock data

```
import someProperty from '/path/someProperty';
import RootState from '/path/types/RootState';

export const mockData: RootState = {
    someProperty
    ...
}
```

Here is a snippet from the webpack file

```
const { mockData } = require('/path/mockData.ts');

...
plugins: [
     new HtmlWebpackPlugin(
        {
            inject: true,
            template: paths.appHtml,
            templateParameters: {
                mockData,
            },
            ...
        }
    )
]
...
```

I tried specifying type in package.json, however converting all requires to imports is too much work at the moment.

What is the best solution to this problem apart from converting the webpack.config to typescript or the mockData to javascript? Neither of those are an option to me right now.

Comment: Use a `require` instead of `import`. *Edit*: inside the mock data file.

Comment: @LuketheGeek Won't that just propagate the problem to the next file, inevitably forcing me to convert the mock to javascript? The imported file is also a typescript file.

Comment: Just set you tsconfig output to commonjs. You can't import or require a TS file into JS directly anyway.